# Strange view of JSON using ng-jsoneditor in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I'm using `ng-jsoneditor` to show and format JSON data in AngularJSapplication. Following [this](https://github.com/angular-tools/ng-jsoneditor) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/angulartools/sd3at5ek/) article.

HTML:

```
<div ng-jsoneditor="onLoad" 
     ng-model="vm.obj.data" 
     options="vm.obj.options" 
     style="width: 400px; height: 300px;">
</div>
```

JS:

```
vm.json = {
"Array": [1, 2, 3],
"Boolean": true,
"Null": null,
"Number": 123,
"Object": {
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d"
},
"String": "Hello World"
 };
vm.obj = {
    data: vm.json,
    options: {
      mode: 'tree'
    }
  };
  $scope.onLoad = function (instance) {
    instance.expandAll();
  };
```

The output looks like this (broken):

[image]

Comment: Does my answer work for you m8?

Comment: Ya thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did forget to include the `CSS` files into your project. This [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gs2wguqw/) includes the CSS file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/master/dist/jsoneditor.min.css">
```